# Is there a way to build this layout with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Hi I am trying to build this layout with flexbox.I provided my current code because i dont know how to move further.Even i posted image how iut should look like under the code.I tried everything but i cant achieve these result. Columns 2,3,5,6,7,8 must be same size. Im new to flex box and i really want to achieve this goal. Thanks for any help.

```css
.tall {
  height: 300px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.box {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.right3collumns {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 2;
}

.box2:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: teal;
}

.box2:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.box2:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  flex: 2;
  background: #22B14C;
}

.right2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.right2small {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ED1C24;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: #00A2E8;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: #FFAEC9;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="right">
    <img src="assets/group.png" alt="group">
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box">Small DIv</div>
    <div class="box">Small DIv</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right2">bigger</div>
  <div class="right2small">smaller</div>
  <div class="right3collumns">
    <div class="box2">Small DIv</div>
    <div class="box2">Small DIv</div>
    <div class="box2">Small DIv</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not believe your picture matches the desired "stacked on each other" output from the  comments.

Comment: i posted the picture down there. This picture should me for LG screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving the layout, I strongly advise, if you can, to use CSS Grid instead.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.grid--col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.grid__item--x2 {
  flex: 2;
}
.grid--main {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid--main">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--x2">
    <div class="grid grid--col">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">2</div>
        <div class="grid__item grid__item--x2">4</div>
        <div class="grid__item">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">3</div>
        <div class="grid__item">5</div>
        <div class="grid__item">6</div>
        <div class="grid__item">7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can modify the CSS/SCSS code to change the layout for different breakpoints using the  CSS @media rules.

For example, you can have everything stacked, when the viewport is less than or equal to 960px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .grid {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.grid--col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid__item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.grid__item--x2 {
  flex: 2;
}
.grid--main {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .grid {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid grid--main">
  <div class="grid__item">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--x2">
    <div class="grid grid--col">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">2</div>
        <div class="grid__item grid__item--x2">4</div>
        <div class="grid__item">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__item">3</div>
        <div class="grid__item">5</div>
        <div class="grid__item">6</div>
        <div class="grid__item">7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help ;)

Comment: Show me an image with the desired result.

Comment: stacked on each other from 1 to 8

Comment: Check the updated POC and the Answer. Also, please update the best answer mark. I don't see how the above answer can be more useful than this one :)

Comment: Can you reconstruct this as a snippet instead of adding a codepen